# Disable 'Default Document' feature in IIS

Tags: windows-7, windows, apache-http-server, iis, iis-7.5

How do I turn off the 'Default Document' feature in IIS so that it won't start when the computer is started?

I want to use XAMPP for local testing, but I can't start Apache until I stop the Default Document, because it is using port 80.

Before I can start Apache, I need to open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager from Control Panel > Administrative Tools. In the manager, I right click on Default Document and select Stop. This frees up port 80.

There was an option to disable the feature, but I tried it and the Default Document feature still started the next time I booted.

What can I do to disable it?

I am using Windows 7 Professional SP1 and IIS 7.5.7600.16385.

Comment: Why not just uninstall IIS?  Why not just change the IIS Default Web Site's port to something other than 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more poking around, I got it figured out.

Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager > Right-click Default Document > View Sites > Right-click Default Web Site > Set Web Site Defaults > Start Automatically > False